# Persisting django channels groups when deploying to production using multiple server instances

Tags: django, redis, production, django-channels

I am deploying my django application that uses web sockets (django channels 2) to production. Using load balancer and two application instances with nginx/gunicorn has been working fine so far but I am wondering about the scalability of the websockets part.

How can I build scalable web sockets architecture that will share the django channels groups among different server instances?

I am using websockets for the live chat functionality so I have to make sure that users added to a specific group will be able to send/receive message from all other users in the same chat room no matter to which server instance the load balancer will point them.

My first thought was to simply use a separate remote server just for redis but I am aware that the vertical scalability will eventually come to an end. What happens when I will need to scale redis servers horizontally?

I've been already using the gunicorn + daphne setup but only with low/dev-testing traffic. I have not tried scaling django channels horizontally yet.

Comment: I _think_ the load balancer will terminate at the server level -- so once the connection is established, it's stuck on that server (for good reason). How are you determining which chat room(s) the user is part of? (URL, etc).

Comment: I don't think It a good idea to have your redis server on the same logical machine as the application in production with or without channels. The same applies to the DB. These should get their own servers so you don't lose access to everything when the app server goes down. Now, if you have redis on another server, then it doesn't really matter how many instances of the chat server you're running since the group names and channel names are stored in the redis server to which they all have access

Comment: @jheld I determine the chat room based on an URL. I will definitely migrate to a separate redis server, I was just wondering what will happen when one redis server instance won't be enough to handle the traffic (but maybe redis is really efficient, I have not tested it yet)

Comment: Agreed with above about how channels_redis works. When the connection starts, you will add that chat group and then construct the handler method(s) accordingly. Redis will hold all of the group and connection info for you.